# How to make a custom TFS Extension (build step) to failed

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I made a new extension for TFS (Build Step), that's running a powershell script.

How can I exit the script that will make this build step to failed? (red "X" in the TFS steps).
I tried exit code 99, when getting an exception but it's still green.

Should I throw exception without catching it from the power shell script?

Comment: Am no expert on this, but in examples I see `exit 1` being used, e.g. here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/

Comment: Thanks Found that by adding "**Write-Error**" print in powershell it will mark the build step as failed, regardless the exit code.

Comment: My experience with TFS 2017 build extensions is that Write-Error also terminates the step. That is not consistent with normal powershell function. My extension expects continuation, so I am going to try Write-Warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that by adding "**Write-Error**" print in powershell it will mark the build step as failed, regardless the exit code:

```
Write-Error "My fail reason."
```

Comment: This works, you can use `Write-Warning`, or `Write-Error` if you want to log errors, if you want to terminate the build use `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate with this question: [How to fail the build from a PowerShell task in TFS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501891/how-to-fail-the-build-from-a-powershell-taks-in-tfs-2015)

> Just using below simple script
>
> ```
>  Write-Error ("Some error")
>  exit 1
> ```

Moreover, you should also be able to return warnings and errors from your script using **[logging commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)**.