# TFS shows success for a failed ANT build

Tags: tfs, ant, build, failonerror

Hi Even though my ant build fails, TFS shows that step as successful and proceeds further. I have tried using failonerror but it seems there are very few tasks for which failonerror works.Is there a workaround so that TFS actually fails when ANT build fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could be able to return warnings and errors from your powershell script using [**logging commands**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/573).  Catch the ant build log first and determine whether the ant build failed. Then  with using `task.logissue type=error` in powershell build task,you could fail the build task and then fail the build.

More details you could take a look at this similar question: [Is it possible to raise and display build warnings from build steps using TFS 2015](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/573)

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How do i use the task.logissue type error once i run a batch script to find that the build is failed. How do i fail both build task and build?

Comment: @uttarabhosale You could write this in a powershell script  such as`Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Test error" ` Then the powershell task will failed  and the entire build will fail. More details please refer *mattbrooks2010* 's comment in above link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/573

Comment: Hi Patrick, I am getting the error logs under Issues. But my powershell script is not recognizing the Build Failed string in the logs. This is the code that i have written: $printCode =[int]$res.StatusCode Write-Host "Result Status Code:" $res.StatusCode "("$printCode")" If([int]$res.StatusCode -eq 0) {Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]Success"} Else {Write-Error "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Test error"} . The status code displayed in the logs is 0 but the Build is Build Failed. Can you please advise?

Comment: I want to compare the string "Build Failed " from the vso logs itself as it is parsing the code as 0 which ideally should be 1 as the build is failing.

Comment: @uttarabhosale Seems the status code of the successful  build should be 200...  You could double check this with a successful build. Take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501891/how-to-fail-the-build-from-a-powershell-task-in-tfs-2015