# TFS build stuck after one script fails

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

I have build in TFS 2012, that run script X among other stuff.

If script X passes, everything is good and TFS build succeed

If script X fails, I get message in TFS that script X execution failed with exit status 1, see log for more details., but the build get stuck until I stop it manually.

I have checked if script X leaves any processes open (with process explorer), but it seems it didnt.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: How did you set in the script X? Scripts must exit with a non-zero exit code to fail.

Comment: script X exited with non-zero exit code, but the build stuck afterwards @andy

Answer (score 0):

Commonly you should get the return error code from your script, you can use “`exit 0`” for success and “`exit 1`” for failures.

Please reference below article and thread for details.

- [Error Handling Poor Man’s RunScript in 2012 Builds](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/error-handling-poor-mans-runscript-in-2012-builds)
- [How to fail the build from a PowerShell task in TFS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501891/how-to-fail-the-build-from-a-powershell-task-in-tfs-2015)

BTW, why don't you consider upgrtading to vNext build (TFS 2015 and later version), in vNext you can set the [Control Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/tasks?view=vsts#task-control-options) for a specific step. And the TFS 2012 is too old, technical support is no longer provided by officials.

See [Why You Should Switch to Build VNext](https://www.nwcadence.com/blog/switch-build-vnext) for details.

Comment: I get exit 1 return code from script X.
but the build stuck as a result.

Comment: @Zakk Could you please share the script X here for troubleshooting?

Comment: this script X i talked about is huge, it runs few batch files, and those few batch files run other batch files, I can't post it here :(

Comment: @Zakk Have you resolved the issue? any update? I'am afraid we cannot do further troubleshooting if no sharing the scripts.

Comment: As I said the script calls 10+ scripts and not in one call, unfortunately I cant share it.

Do you have any tips how I can proceed or fix the issue?

Comment: @Zakk Have you resolved the issue? Generally exit the session will did the trick, but based on limited information can not figure it out....