# VSTS build doesn't fail on failed tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS to run protractor e2e test cases. I have a npm custom task that run the tests and even if the test fails, vsts build doesn't fail.

How can I make the vsts build fail?

Comment: Does your custom task return a non-zero exit code when the tests fail?

Comment: @DanielMann Process exited with error code 1

Comment: Can you share the entire logs? I cannot reproduce this issue at my side.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `Write-Error` in combination with an exit 1 to fail a task:

```
Write-Error ("Some error")
exit 1
```

Check the case below:

[How to fail the build from a PowerShell task in TFS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501891/how-to-fail-the-build-from-a-powershell-task-in-tfs-2015)

Comment: I am already returning error code as 1. Why do I need to do this? Why VSTS can't understand the exit/error code return by npm task?

Comment: You could check [Task Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md), using `##vso[task.complete]current operation` to finish timeline record for current task, set task result and current operation.